# How many different possible outcomes are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be a $n$ long word in which you have to preform $n$ amount of actions. Let the word consists of all As
$$AA...A$$ 
An action consists of picking any letter and changing to the letter after it so for example on a 3 letter word $$AAA \rightarrow_{action} AAB$$

How many possible outcomes are there while not counting permutations so for example $AC$ and $CA$ are counted as the same outcome?

Comment: I think this is better to view as an array of zeroes, where an action consists of incrementing a number. That way you avoid the issue of what happens to $Z$.

Comment: **side note:** This can also be done by summing multinomial and binomial coefficients in the correct way, however, this is far more difficult than using the partition function, as @orlp answered with. Indeed, using binomial and multinomial coefficients will still require you to sum over all partitions.

Answer (score 2):

If we view the problem as an array of $n$ zeroes, where an action increments the number, your problem is equivalent to finding the number of [partitions of $n$ without regard for order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

The partition function $p(n)$ gives your answer, for more information see [A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041).